# Filter out values from python mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, list, filter

I am using mysql.connector in python to get a list of values from a database.

can you please help extract each value from the list separately

my code is as below

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_localhost, user=user, password=password, database=database)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("select  * from settings" )
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

and the result I am getting is a list as follow

```
[(0, 3232235535L, 0, 12, 12.1, 22.5, 29.0)]
```

What I would like to do then is get each value (being integer or float) separately from the list above

Comment: I wanted to get all values in the row actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for each in results[0]:
    ...
```

Or if you do want assign them to variables:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = results[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for Value in results:
   # do what you need
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetchone` instead of `fetchall`:

```
result = cursor.fetchone()
for field in result:
    print field
```